# ListView and it's "weird" behavior. How can i solve this situation?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-recyclerview

As you should know, `ListView` recycles the view. But i want to work with elements that can be clicked and expanded. Like i already did: 
[image]

But it was completely messed up, even using:

```
View checklayout = convertView;
if(checklayout == null){
        checklayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_cell, null);
    }
```

When some opened expandable views goes out of the screen, the recycled one, which shouldn't be expandable, receives the vanished's layout. Only view that has "1 AVALIAÇÃO LANÇADA" should open, and show it's content. I add this content by using `if(qtdAvaliacoes > 0)` that is a property of my Object that comes from ArrayList<>.

I "solved" this disabling the recycler, with:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Once my listView will only receives 5~10 rows. But i know that isn't a good practice. While i'm writting this question, i found a solution, calling my object before inflate any view, then checking the property:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View checklayout = convertView;
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final Disciplina disciplina = lista.get(position);

    if(checklayout == null || disciplina.getQtdAvaliacoes() == 0){
        checklayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_cell, null);
    }

    final View layout = checklayout;
```

But I don't think this is the best way to do this. I read something about Tags, but was little confused. I think if i could bind these onClick methods to the row position it would be better.

Any ideas ? Or is my solution good at you, developer's, point of view.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to not do subinflates within a list item.  Do it via view visibilities instead, making the inflated part GONE if you don't want it to display yet.  You'll just have to explicitly set the visibility of that view in every call to getView

Comment: Doesn't it make my app loads more data ? Because user won't always need those tables. Furthermore, the table is dynamically populated. Thanks !

Comment: It would require you to have more views.  The actual data difference is minimal, although the initial inflate time will go up a bit.  There may be a slight hit to perf, but pretty much any solution you find will hit perf-  inflating into a recycled view is generally hard to do.  The other way to do it is to have 2 view types-  a fully inflated view type and an uninflated view type, and keep track of which items should be inflated or not.  That's more work but would reduce most of the perf hits (although it may take more data in the end, depending on how much the recycler holds onto).